# Entity Framework Code First Migration Files Source Control

Tags: entity-framework, version-control, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Wanted to ask this bluntly as I can't seem to find the answer out there.

When I run 'Add-Migration...' 3 new file migration files are created (.cs, .resx, .Designer.cs).  In regards to source control, which files should I commit to my repo and what files can I ignore?  I'm only interested in the files absolutely necessary to reconstruct my tables if needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> When I run 'Add-Migration...' 3 new file migration files are created
>   (.cs, .resx, .Designer.cs). In regards to source control, which files
>   should I commit to my repo and what files can I ignore?

All 3 files are necessary to reconstruct your database.

- the `.cs` file contains the `Up` and `Down` method to help you, respectively, updgrade or downgrade your database.
- the `.resx` file contains the metadata that is used by migrations. It contains the name of the default schema you use (dbo is the default value) and a snapshot of the model at the time the migration was generated.
- the `.Designer.cs` is here because of the presence of `.resx`. It contains properties that make easy to access settings on the `.resx` file.

All 3 files need to be committed and pushed in your source control and no one should edit them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer as well as the explanation for each file's purpose.

Comment: @codenotfound "It contains ... a snapshot of the model at the time the migration was generated" -- why should it contain that? What if 2 people created their own migrations? Say, M1 and M2. Then they both refer to the same parent.

Comment: Now in my project when I execute "Remove-Migration", no file is actually being removed, though the app snapshot is changed as if I removed one migration. It's ridiculous.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Since he is only interested in recreating tables what about just using DbContext.cs to add a migration and update-database command to generate the database?